# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)

Tags: php, wordpress, laragon

I am having this common php error: ‘Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\laragon\www\testone\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 312’
 I increased the memory limit in the wp-config:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

in the .htaccess

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value upload_max_filesize 12M
php_value post_max_size 13M
```

and created a php.ini file  in the wp-content/plugins files (the php.ini didn’t exist after downloading laragon)

```
memory_limit = 128M ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
upload_max_filesize = 12M
post_max_size = 13M
```

I also created a info.php file and it says that the max memory limit is 256M Nothing works ANy help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I changed the memory limit many times to different sized but it didnt work either!

Comment: Hey so it looks like you want to change the php.ini configuration of your system.
It looks like you're on windows so can I ask what server setup you're using?

Comment: HI, yes I'm using Laragon

Comment: Is this something that happened "out of the box" (before you've changed anyting) or does it occur while doing something specific in your code?

Comment: It started at the very beginning without adding any code, I already changed the memory limit and it worked fine. It happened again after I added a container in a template-contactus.php file. I'm also lookign at disabling the Opcache php extension

Answer (score 0):

So using Laragon and citing this link https://forum.laragon.org/topic/610/laragon-3-1-4-released-supports-php-7-2

It looks like you can edit the php.ini config through the Laragon menu. Once you've made your changes I suggest restarting Laragon and seeing if the changes you've made have taken effect.

Comment: I tried to click again and again but the file doesn' open. it's supposed to be located in the usr/tpl but I already checked and it's not there either...weird!

Comment: hello, sorry for the very late reply and thank you for your help! I ended up uninstalling everything and reinstalling it. The problem came from a bootstrap corrupted file!

Comment: Well done finding the issue. It’s stuff like that which can stump people for a very long time!